# Use list in "where col in" clause along with other clauses in mssql query in python

Tags: python-2.7

I have 2 lists 
date_list   =  [2016-01,2016-02,2016-01,2016-01]
string_list =  [abc, ghf, rtks]
I need to make a sql query to one of the tables (table1) to retrieve a column data (col1) where col2 is a iteration from list1 and col3 in date_list

```
for r in string_list:
    elements= ','.join('?' * len(date_list))
    cursor.execute("select col1 from table1 where col2 = ? and col3 in (%s)"r,% elements,tuple(date_list))
    abcd = cursor.fetchall()
```

This gives me error. However, if I remove col2 clause from the query, it executes fine. Please help me the add multiple clauses to this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to stick your `r` parameter in the wrong place.  You want to pass that in as a parameter value.

```
for r in string_list:
    elements = ','.join('?' * len(date_list))
    cursor.execute(
        "select col1 from table1 where col2 = ? and col3 in (%s)" % elements,
        (r,) + tuple(date_list)
    )
    abcd = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, @zatziky answered it before.

Comment: It's not quite the same. He's generating the entire query string with the values inserted into the query. That of course leaves you vulnerable to sql injection attacks. I suspect your code was already set up to use sql parameters correctly, there's no reason to break that now.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. So I will use your code. This also works for me seamlessly

Answer (score 0):

Man, to me it seems that you are mixing 2 string formatting strategies.

Try to rewrite your code using `%` formatting only. Something like:

```
string_list = ["abc", "ghf", "rtks"]
date_list = ["2016-01","2016-02","2016-01","2016-01"]
for r in string_list:
    cursor.execute(
      "select col1 from table1 where col2 = '%s' and col3 in %s" 
       % (r,tuple(date_list))
    )
```

This yields this sql query:

```
select col1 from table1 where col2 = 'abc' and col3 in ('2016-01', '2016-02', '2016-01', '2016-01')
select col1 from table1 where col2 = 'ghf' and col3 in ('2016-01', '2016-02', '2016-01', '2016-01')
select col1 from table1 where col2 = 'rtks' and col3 in ('2016-01', '2016-02', '2016-01', '2016-01')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what about the string_list variable. how should I include that. Or, if I want to add more options in the where clause, how do I do that. Please help

Comment: Ok, but please rewrite the code using `%` as I am of lost in the part `(%s)"r,%`

Comment: I tried exactly as you suggested. It now gives an error: 

TypeError: float argument required, not str

What does this mean.

Comment: Strings should be escaped. `'abc'`

Comment: The lists are in the format ['2016-01','2016-02'] or ['abc', 'ghf'] and are passed as : abc and 2016-01. Then what is float.